# Non-stop running service - Thread, AsyncTask or Executor?

Tags: android

I am programming an app that should get some values from a website and notify if some conditions are true. For this porpose I created a service, that should run non-stop and start an alarm.

In the service documentation it says:

> Note that services, like other application objects, run in the main
>   thread of their hosting process. This means that, if your service is
>   going to do any CPU intensive (such as MP3 playback) or blocking
>   (such as networking) operations, it should spawn its own thread in
>   which to do that work.

Therefore I am currently creating a new thread in onStartCommand() of the service which contains the code to run. 
Some network actions is doing another class, where I am creating another thread. Is that a good practice?

In the documentation of AsyncTask it says:

> If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time, it is
>   highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the
>   java.util.concurrent package such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and
>   FutureTask.

Is it recommendable to make use of one of the named APIs?

Here is an extract of the code i am currently using:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
private MyClass x = new MyClass();

@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

            tWorker = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               while(!tWorker.isInterrupted()) { 
                    if(x.alarm()) { //action here }
               }
            });
            tWorker.start();
    }
}


public clas MyClass{
   public boolean alarm(){
      //get HTML, extract value and return true or false in a new thread
   }
}
```

Is this practice recommedable or better to use another option?

Edit:
Which one of the named APIs should I prefer for my case of usage?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is best practice to use the APIs as stated by the documentation. Using Java's threading system can lead to problems on Android for multiple reasons such as apps that kill background processes etc. Your thread will likely end up stopping all the time. It's just less hassle to use the Android specific classes since they are designed to work with all the things that go on on an Android device.